# How can i get values from chart on Google Trends

Tags: charts, google-trends

how can i get values from chart on Google Trends.

f.e. 'Search interest' value

[Example chart on this website](https://trends.google.com/trends/story/GB_lnk_Nbv6sAAwAADPuM_en)

[Screen with explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLVrP.png)

I tried to extract data using 'selenium' (in python), but without success.

Thanks in advance for suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Pytrends Module :

`https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytrends/4.0.0`

This is An unoffical API for google trends which you can download this data from